# PHP MYSQL Не работает вывод запроса из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Нужно, чтоб выводило данные о новом товаре из всех таблиц, но выводит либо только данные из 1 таблицы, либо данные из 2 таблицы, но вместе никак. В phpmyadmin все работает, а на сайте - нет.

```
$sql = "SELECT cat1.*, cat2.* FROM goods_cat1 AS cat1, goods_cat2 AS cat2 WHERE cat1.new = 1 AND cat2.new = 1";
$reg = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reg)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $text = $row["text"];
    $img = "images/" . $row["img"];

    // тут вывод
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, где у вас таблицы и что нужно получить из таблиц. Если я правильно понял у вас две таблицы `goods_cat1` и `goods_cat2`, и в них есть столбец `new`, и вам нужно получить все значения из обоих таблиц, где столбцы `new` равны `1` верно? Если так, то могу помочь составить запрос)

Comment: Да, именно так)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, пришел к данному решению, которое идеально работает. Все остальные решения с JOIN итд не работают непонято почему.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM goods_cat1 AS cat1 WHERE new = 1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM goods_cat2 WHERE new = 1";
```

Так же, если вы можете еще как-то помочь, то ожидаю ваши варианты для проверки)